# Concatenate based on cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, pivot-table, excel-2013

I have a table in Excel composed of three columns:

```
Status  Emp    Achievement
1       Emp1      98.44%
2       Emp2      91.44%
3       Emp3      82.54
2       Emp4      89.47
2       Emp5      89.02
```

I need to out each status with the corresponding `emp` and achievement as shown:

```
Emp1 = 98.44%
Emp2 = 91.44% , Emp4 = 89.47% , Emp5 89.02%
Emp3 = 82.54%
```

I did a For to Next loop but the result shows only the first one.  Need help in the correct code.

Comment: Agree with @pnuts. It seems to me that you are trying to do this with VBA? Add your code, your trouble with it and fix the tags on your question. And surely help is on the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However the result may be achieved with formulae.

With a PivotTable (in case the raw data may not be sorted) with `Status` and `Emp` for ROWS and `Achievement` in VALUES and (for layout as in image) these formulae copied down to suit:

in I2: `=F2&" = "&TEXT(G2,"0.00%")`
in J2: `=IF(E2<>"",I2,J1&" , "&I2)`
in K2: `=OR(AND(E2<>"",E3<>""),AND(E2="",E3<>""))`

then filter ColumnK to select `TRUE`.

[image: SO27545823 example]